# Rails error message: Undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have just added this line of code: `<%= image_tag tweet.user.avatar %>` to the following view file

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(tweet) do %>  
  <div class="tweet py-3 px-2">
    <% if(Time.zone.now - tweet.created_at) > 1.day %>
      <%= image_tag tweet.user.avatar %>
      <p><%= tweet.user.display_name %>@<%= tweet.user.username %> . <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%b %-d") %></p>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag tweet.user.avatar %>
      <p><%= tweet.user.display_name %>@<%= tweet.user.username %> . <%= time_ago_in_words(tweet.created_at) %></p>
    <% end %>
    <p class="mb-0"><%= tweet.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The line of code is meant to display an image which is attached to the user through ActiveStorage. I check in the console, and the image is sucessfully loaded:

```
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x000000010813cf50
 @name="avatar",
 @record=
  #<User id: 3, email: "rajdeep@gmail", created_at: "2023-03-30 08:29:06.001223000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-03-30 21:35:17.296341000 +0000", username: "rj_deep", display_name: "Raja Deep">>
```

However, I am obtaining this message once it is time to display the loaded image:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
 | 
        named_route = if model.persisted?
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^):
4:     <%= image_tag tweet.user.avatar %>
5:       <p><%= tweet.user.display_name %>@<%= tweet.user.username %> . <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%b %-d") %></p>
6:     <% else %>
7:       <%= image_tag tweet.user.avatar %>
8:       <p><%= tweet.user.display_name %>@<%= tweet.user.username %> . <%= time_ago_in_words(tweet.created_at) %></p>
9:     <% end %>
10:     <p class="mb-0"><%= tweet.body %></p>
```

Before I had added that line of code, all the rest of the info (the tweet, the display_name, the user_name and the tweet's creation-time) were successfully displayed.

I have no idea what this refers to. I used my code editor to look up `named_route = if model.persisted?` thinking that it might be a line of code in one of the project's files and that this might give me a better idea as to what this error message is signaling to me, but there is no such line in the project.

Don't know if this is related, but the project uses devise for user authentication and turbo-links for immediate page reload (which was not working, but was not interfering with display either).

The project is found here `https://github.com/German-Cobian/Twitter-Rails`, in case you need to get a better idea of the project's design.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you get if you call `tweet.user.avatar.attached?`, sounds like you are trying to display an attachment but there's no attachment. You might want to do `image_tag(tweet.user.avatar) if tweet.user.avatar.attached?` for example

Comment: Hello arieljuod. If I go to rails console and query `User.last.avatar.attached?` I get `=> true`. `User.last` being the user that I am currently logged into the rails app with. So it seems that the image, or avatar, is effectively attached.

Comment: but `tweet.user` is not necessarily `current_user`, you have to check if all users have an avatar.

Comment: "turbo-links for immediate page reload". [Turbo Drive](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive) completely replaces Turbolinks. Do NOT add Turbolinks to a Rails 7 application. Nothing good will come from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using delegation to remove the Law of Demeter violations:

```
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :avatar, 
           :display_name, 
           :username, 
           to: :user
end
```

Then remove the duplication and complexity out of the view into a helper*:

```
module TweetsHelper
  def tweet_tagline(t) 
    "#{t.display_name}@#{t.username} . #{tweet_timestamp(t.created_at)}"
  end

  def tweet_avatar(t, **options)
    image_tag t.avatar, **options if t.avatar
  end

  private

  def tweet_timestamp(t)
    if t.today?
      t.strftime("%b %-d")
    else
      time_ago_in_words(t)     
    end
  end
end
```

Now the view can just spit out markup in the simplest way possible:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(tweet) do %>  
  <div class="tweet py-3 px-2">
    <%= tweet_avatar(tweet) %>
    <p><%= tweet_tagline(tweet) %></p>
    <p class="mb-0"><%= tweet.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: * A decorator would be a lot less awkward.

Comment: I solved the issue! It had to do with hotwire/turbo on Rails7. Turns out that turbo-requests are processed by the controller in a http format and not as turbo_stream. So I changed my controllers in accordance and noit only is the image_tag displaying the avatar now, but all tweets are being displayed without a page reload. Thank you all. I believe my post did not fully explain my problem, but the logic of the display was to involved for me to unwind.

Comment: That isn't actually correct. Rails will actually implicitly render `turbo.html.erb` templates when the accept type is vnd/turbostream. If the corresponding view isn't found it falls back to HTML. This behavior is unique to `vnd/turbostream`.